# Find free timings

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

This is the database schema:

```
   CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
      `id` int(2) NOT NULL,
      `start` time NOT NULL,
      `end` time NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO `bookings` VALUES(1, '13:00:00', '14:30:00');
    INSERT INTO `bookings` VALUES(2, '15:00:00', '16:00:00');
```

I tried to run the following query, to find the free times between '10:00:00' AND '18:00:00':

```
SELECT free_from, free_until
FROM (SELECT a.end AS free_from,
             (SELECT MIN(c.start)
              FROM bookings c
              WHERE c.start>a.end
             ) as free_until
      FROM bookings a
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM bookings b
                        WHERE b.start BETWEEN a.end AND a.end + 1
                       ) AND
            a.end BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
     ) t
```

The output generated is:

```
free_from   free_until
14:30:00    15:00:00
16:00:00    NULL
```

Why is there a NULL in the end? Please help me solve this problem. Expected output should be:

```
free_from   free_until
10:00:00    13:00:00
14:30:00    15:00:00
16:00:00    18:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Something to think about...

```
SELECT NULL id,NULL start, '09:59:59' end
UNION
SELECT * FROM bookings
UNION
SELECT NULL,'18:00:01',NULL;
+------+----------+----------+
| id   | start    | end      |
+------+----------+----------+
| NULL | NULL     | 09:59:59 |
|    1 | 13:00:00 | 14:30:00 |
|    2 | 15:00:00 | 16:00:00 |
| NULL | 18:00:01 | NULL     |
+------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: the output here is the start and end times. however I need the free times, as shown in the expected output

Comment: Well, you have all you need to know in this answer. If it still isn't clear to you, you have `null` in your solution because you can't select what isn't there. Therefore you have to create it. Upvoted for the "teaching to fish" rather than the "feeding" attitude :)